# How to solve seaborn scatterplot ValueError: string of single character colors as a color sequence is not supported?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a bunch of lines using seaborn to color them based on a variable, then I've done some peakfinding to label the specific peaks. For some reason, sns.lineplot works exactly as expected, however, when trying to use sns.scatterplot with almost identical parameters it throws a value error about my colors being unsupported.

Versions for packages I think are relevent:
python: 3.8.10
matplotlib: 3.4.3
seaborn: 0.11.2
pandas: 1.3.0
numpy: 1.21.0

minimum reproducible example:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data
x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y=np.sin(x)
df_test1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x,
                        'y':y,
                        'color': ['Penguin']*50+['Octopus']*50})

# find peaks from the data that we want to mark on our graph
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df_test1['color'].unique():
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    pks = signal.find_peaks(df_test1.loc[df_test1['color']==c, 'y'],
                                        height=0.2, width=2)
    data['x'] = df_test1.loc[df_test1['color']==c,'x'].iloc[pks[0]]
    data['Height'] = pks[1]['peak_heights']
    data['color'] = c
    df_test2 = pd.concat([df_test2, data], ignore_index=True)
    
# printing the peaks dataframe just to confirm there are things to plot.
print(df_test2)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8,8), sharey='row', sharex=True)
# plotting the line I want - this works
sns.lineplot(data=df_test1, x='x', y='y', hue='color', estimator=None, legend=False, ax=axes[0])
sns.lineplot(data=df_test1, x='x', y='y', hue='color', estimator=None, legend=False, ax=axes[1])
# labeling the peaks - This is where I get my error
sns.scatterplot(data=df_test2, x='x', y='Height', hue='color', style='color', legend=False, ax=axes[0])
# the work around I found is comment out the line above, and run the line below:
sns.lineplot(data=df_test2, x='x', y='Height', hue='color', estimator=None, legend=False, ax=axes[1],
            markers=True, marker='X', linestyle='',)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In making a minimal reproducible example I found a workaround, but I'm wondering if this is a seaborn bug or something I am misunderstanding. I also spent a lot of time searching for a solution, so I'm hoping this post can help someone else in the same boat.

Edit: Removed the estimator parameter (as per Trenton) and still the same error. I'll try updating my seaborn and matplotlib though.

Edit2: Updating seaborn and matplotlib worked, so my guess is that there was a bug that got corrected.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: PathCollection.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'estimator'` because `sns.scatterplot` doesn't have an `estimator` parameter. Remove that, and the code works without issue. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGEEg.png). I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible / caused by a typo. As you can see from the image, `sns.scatterplot(data=df_test2, x='x', y='Height', hue='color', style='color', legend=False, ax=axes[0])` plots the peaks without issue. `seaborn v0.12.1` and `matplotlib v3.6.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating seaborn and matplotlib worked, so my guess is that there was a bug that got corrected.